# sobrepor histrogramas

Tags: r, ggplot2, histograma

bom dia
Eu gostaria de criar um histograma com 26 espécies no eixo x e a porcentagem de influencia da caça comercial na redução de cada espécie (coluna ''depletion_rate'') no eixo y. Eu também gostaria de sobrepor os histogramas com certa transparência de acordo com o nível trófico de cada espécie, ou seja, seriam 3 histogramas sobrepostos referentes aos níveis herb, oni e carn.
Não sei como colocar estas 3 colunas em meu script. Já tentei de diversas maneiras, mas o máximo que consigo é plotar duas variáveis.

Obs.: eu não queria organizar a tabela colocando cada nível trófico em uma coluna porque várias linhas ficariam vazias, afinal uma espécie só pode pertencer a um nível trófico.

```js
library(ggplot2)

head(CAUSA_FINAL_FB)
Dataset<-CAUSA_FINAL_FB
# Overlaid histograms

ggplot(Dataset, aes(x=specie, fill=trofic) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="identity")
```

```html
trophic depletion_rate specie
carn     0.8         Lept_serv
carn     0.8         Lyc_pict
carn     1.6         Can_mes
carn    18.4      Pant_pa
carn    11.2       Oryct_afer
carn    51.2         Croc_croc
carn     0         Pant_le
herb    72         Thry_swin
herb    23.2         Hys_afri
herb    48         Sylv_grim
herb    100         Trag_scri
herb    100         Red_aru
herb    14.4         Hipp_eq
herb    16         Trag_oryx
herb    81.6         Sync_caf
herb    1.6         Lox_afric
oni        7.2         Otol_cras
oni        1.6         Miop_tal
oni        14.4         Lep_cap
oni         0         Genet_gen
oni        20.8         Phil_mont
oni        72.8         Chlor_cyn
oni         5.6         Cerc_mit
oni        43.2         Civet_civ
oni       100         Pota_larv
oni        22.4      Hipp_amph
```

[image: figura de exemplo]

Comment: Olá @Fran Braga. Nesse caso, imagino que o mais adequado é o gráfico de barras, concorda? Todos os seus dados foram esses que você colocou na pergunta?

Comment: Ei Guilherme 
Tenho mais colunas referentes a outras causas, mas pensei em montar um quadro para  cada causa pelo comando facet_wrap(). Muito obrigada pela sugestão (to aqui me perguntando, por que não pensei nisto ao invés de insistir com o histograma rsrsrs).

Answer (score 5):

Veja se o seguinte é o que pretende.
Eu incluí o pacote `ggpubr` para rodar os nomes das espécies no eixo `x`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(dados, aes(specie, depletion_rate)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser mudar as cores use as funções `scale_color_manual` e `sclae_fill_manual`. Veja as páginas de ajuda para uma lista de funções que permitem definir cores.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(specie, depletion_rate)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5, aes(colour = trophic, fill = trophic,
                            group = trophic)) +
  scale_color_manual("trophic", values = c("turquoise", "salmon", "yellow")) +
  scale_fill_manual("trophic", values = c("turquoise", "salmon", "yellow")) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 55)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados em formato `dput`.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(trophic = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
.Label = c("carn", "herb", "oni"), class = "factor"), 
depletion_rate = c(0.8, 0.8, 1.6, 18.4, 11.2, 
51.2, 0, 72, 23.2, 48, 100, 100, 14.4, 16, 81.6,
1.6, 7.2, 1.6, 14.4, 0, 20.8, 72.8, 5.6, 43.2, 
100, 22.4), specie = structure(c(11L, 13L, 1L, 
18L, 15L, 5L, 17L, 24L, 9L, 22L, 26L, 21L, 8L, 25L, 
23L, 12L, 16L, 14L, 10L, 6L, 19L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
20L, 7L), .Label = c("Can_mes", "Cerc_mit", 
"Chlor_cyn", "Civet_civ", "Croc_croc", "Genet_gen", 
"Hipp_amph", "Hipp_eq", "Hys_afri", "Lep_cap", 
"Lept_serv", "Lox_afric", "Lyc_pict", "Miop_tal", 
"Oryct_afer", "Otol_cras", "Pant_le", "Pant_pa", 
"Phil_mont", "Pota_larv", "Red_aru", "Sylv_grim", 
"Sync_caf", "Thry_swin", "Trag_oryx", "Trag_scri"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

Comment: Tá ótimo! Muito obrigada
Uma última pergunta, sobre as cores, meu gráfico ficou com uma escala de três tons de azul. Você sabe que comando uso para colocar as ESPECÍFICAS cores que quero para cada nível trófico (1, 2 e 3)?

Comment: @FranBraga Feito, veja o novo gráfico.